# Keep class after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, session-cookies, session-storage

I have a wordpress plugin that adds a class (.ig_hide) to a div (.icegram), then after page refresh the class disappears.

I need to override this, I'd like to keep this class in place after a refresh, **without using a js plugin or editing the wordpress plugin**, is there a way to do this ?

I have something like this so far :

```
jQuery('.icegram').on('click', '.ig_close', function(){
jQuery('.action_bar_135').addClass('ig_save').click();

        if(supports_storage()) localStorage['save'] = true;
        return false;
});

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
     if(localStorage['save'] == 'true') jQuery('.ig_save').hide();
 });
```

Comment: It is possible but I will recommend some type of routing instead of using session storage

Comment: Essentially, you need to somehow store this information in a location that doesn't get wiped on refresh. ``localStorage`` and cookies are an easy key-storage solution, that you could save data to, and load up the "state" on page load. Alternatively, as @ankit31894 suggested, there are additional ways to represent/store state such a different routes.

Comment: Why don't you simpy do `$(".icegram").addClass("ig_hide")` on `document.ready`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao because at first I need it not to show. Basically, once it's clicked the class is added. I need that class to stay added after the refresh, ultimately only for the current session.

I'm not a wiz in js, any ideas how this would be written out?

Comment: as said by others, you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` and along side if you dont wanna make changes to the plugin, the option you are left with is `mutationObserver` on the `element` to which class will be added. Withing `mutationObserver` you can add functionality to store in either of the above storage and on the `document.ready` you can write a functionality to check storage values and add class/not..

Comment: What I'm asking is if you can show the code you would use if using local or sessionstorage. I was able to roughly put this together, I've revised the quesiton